# Cocos2D v3 and Physics simulation on server

Tags: multiplayer, cocos2d

I'm trying to develop a real time multiplayer game using Cococs2d v3. The game is basically a side scrolling racing game. I wanted to develop the client using Cococs2d for iPhone, and the server side using Java.
I've read about real time networking and the difficulties I can encounter, but also how can I overcome it. The most helpful articles I read was Valve's, Glenn Fiedler's game networking article and Gabriel Gambetta's article on fast-paced multiplayer games.
I can attach links to those articles if anyone is interested :)

I have come to the conclusion that the physics should be implemented both on the client side and the server side. Using cocos2d v3 this could be done without any problems on the client side, but how can I use the same physics simulation in my server written in Java?
For example how could the server know if there's a hill the client player is climbing, or if there's an obstacle it need to collide with? The physics engine the client use is written in Objective C..

Am I missing something over here?
If my question is not clear enough, please tell me and I will explain it in more details.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'd basically need to load the same complete physics world on the server and play the same game on the server as you do on the clients, and let clients and server communicate to keep everything the same everywhere. I'm no expert on this, but I think if you don't use the exact same physics engine, you're likely to get different results from your calculations, so it'll be hard to keep server and clients in sync.

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the comment. I am aware that the physics world should be similar in both client and server, but if I'm using cocos2d physics engine how could I simulate the same thing in the server? I'm open for any ideas even if it means to ditch Java for the server developing. Thank you.

Comment: The naive solution would be to ditch java and basically run the same cocos2d code on your server, except for rendering. But as I said, I'm not exactly an expert on neither physics engines or server-client stuff, so I'm afraid someone else will have to talk about the details.

Comment: 1. Can you share those 3 article's URL   2. Did you find any solution ?